# Access google news div from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create chrome extension that will show only the top stories from google news page. Now through permission in menifest will I be able to get the required div of google news page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information on any page if you request corresponding domain permissions in manifest. Instead of parsing google news html it probably would be easier to parse its rss feed instead (if there is one).